# Kibana Site cant be reached

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, wazuh

So I'm trying to setup a Wazuh server, after installing it I got greeted with the message`This site can't be reached`. When I try to curl the IP with port like this: curl http://192.168.1.108:5601 it doesnt show anything, not even an error. Kibana is running as a service and even gives the green signal and http link to get to the panel.

kibana.yml:

```
# Kibana is served by a back end server. This setting specifies the port to use.
   
#server.port: 5601
    
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English - en , by default , Chinese - zh-CN .
#i18n.locale: "en"
#server.ssl.key: /path/to/your/server.key
    
# Optional settings that provide the paths to the PEM-format SSL certificate and key files.

# These files are used to verify the identity of Kibana to Elasticsearch and are required when
# xpack.security.http.ssl.client_authentication in Elasticsearch is set to required.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificate: /path/to/your/client.crt
#elasticsearch.ssl.key: /path/to/your/client.key

# Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate
# authority for your Elasticsearch instance.
#elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: [ "/path/to/your/CA.pem" ]

# To disregard the validity of SSL certificates, change this setting's value to 'none'.
#elasticsearch.ssl.verificationMode: full

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch to respond to pings. Defaults to the value of
# the elasticsearch.requestTimeout setting.
#elasticsearch.pingTimeout: 1500

# Time in milliseconds to wait for responses from the back end or Elasticsearch. This value
# must be a positive integer.
#elasticsearch.requestTimeout: 30000

# List of Kibana client-side headers to send to Elasticsearch. To send *no* client-side
# headers, set this value to [] (an empty list).
#elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist: [ authorization ]

# Header names and values that are sent to Elasticsearch. Any custom headers cannot be overwritten
# by client-side headers, regardless of the elasticsearch.requestHeadersWhitelist configuration.
#elasticsearch.customHeaders: {}

# Time in milliseconds for Elasticsearch to wait for responses from shards. Set to 0 to disable.
#elasticsearch.shardTimeout: 30000

# Time in milliseconds to wait for Elasticsearch at Kibana startup before retrying.
#elasticsearch.startupTimeout: 5000

# Logs queries sent to Elasticsearch. Requires logging.verbose set to true.
#elasticsearch.logQueries: false

# Specifies the path where Kibana creates the process ID file.
#pid.file: /var/run/kibana.pid

# Enables you to specify a file where Kibana stores log output.
#logging.dest: stdout

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output.
#logging.silent: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to suppress all logging output other than error messages.
#logging.quiet: false

# Set the value of this setting to true to log all events, including system usage information
# and all requests.
logging.verbose: true

# Set the interval in milliseconds to sample system and process performance
# metrics. Minimum is 100ms. Defaults to 5000.
#ops.interval: 5000

# Specifies locale to be used for all localizable strings, dates and number formats.
# Supported languages are the following: English - en , by default , Chinese - zh-CN .
#i18n.locale: "en"
```

Changed parameters elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: my-application

cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]

node.name: node-1
```

Changed parameter filebeat.yml

```
output.elasticsearch.hosts: ['http://192.168.1.108:9200']
```

I've followed the following guide to set it all up: https://documentation.wazuh.com/3.13/installation-guide/installing-wazuh-manager/linux/ubuntu/wazuh_server_packages_ubuntu.html

Curl http://192.168.1.108:9200 gives the following:

```
{
  "name" : "node-1",
  "cluster_name" : "my-application",
  "cluster_uuid" : "VbrZJIilQgSDPZSdvKKSjA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.9.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "d34da0ea4a966c4e49417f2da2f244e3e97b4e6e",
    "build_date" : "2020-09-23T00:45:33.626720Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.6.2",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `server.host: 192.168.1.108` inside **kibana.yml** configuration file.

> server.host:
>
> This setting specifies the host of the back end server. To allow
> remote users to connect, set the value to the IP address or DNS name
> of the Kibana server. Default: "localhost"

From [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.9/settings.html)

Comment: @LemonFridge  If my answer was helpful please feel free to accept/upvote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By setting `server.host` in your **kibana.yml** file, you will be able to set kibana to be seen through network or not. If you set this as your IP or to `0.0.0.0` you make it possible to be seen through network, not just from local.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be change # on the #server.port: 5601  , and check the port from Firewall . Maybe this port is not open .